# How can I upload the image to server without refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, image-uploading

Actually I load the picture on the server. But once we do this, the page refreshes. ***My goal is to do this without refreshing the page.*** How can I do that? Is there anyone who can help?
In the code below I write `onsubmit = "return false"` in the form. But the picture is not uploaded to the server because the page is not refresh in this way.

VIEW

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("create_conference", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "registerFormValidation", onsubmit = "return false" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="btn btn-default btn-wd btn-info btn-fill btn-file input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-image"></i> <input type="file" name="file" id="imgInp" accept="image/*">
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="image-path" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="enter-room-name">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name of Room" class="form-control" required="true" id="room-name" autocomplete="false" style="text-transform:uppercase">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="add-room-submit" class="btn btn-info btn-round  btn-wd">Save</button>
    </div>
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult create_conference(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var path = "";
    if (file != null)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            //for checking uploaded file is image or not
            if(Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower()==".jpg"
                || Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower()==".png"
                || Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower()==".gif"
                || Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower()==".jpeg")
            {
                path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/assets/img/conference-img"), file.FileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                ViewBag.UploadSuccess = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return View();
    //return Redirect("rooms"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't read it as base64 using the fileReader or using a iframe...
Simply turn the form element into a FormData and send that to the server.

A good idea is not trying to specify method/url in the javascript keep it as general as possible and have the html markup do what it was meant to do (defining things) then you can use this function for more forms and it got a more graceful degration if javascript where turned of

```
function turnFormToAjax(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()

  var form = evt.target
  var fd = new FormData(fd)

  fetch(form.target, {method: form.method, body: fd})
    .then(function(res) {
      // done uploading
    })
}

document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = turnFormToAjax
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to base64 and ajax call it. Make sure the backend converts it back to an image file before saving it.

I've done it with jquery in the past.

This is the important part:

I've done it with jquery. This is the important part.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#imageFile').change(function(evt) {

        var files = evt.target.files;
        var file = files[0];


        if (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                document.getElementById('preview').src = e.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            // console.log(file.name)
            var filename = file.name
            console.log(filename);
        }
    });
```

make sure filename sends.

Comment: I do not know how to do this. Can you adapt my code?

Comment: I've done it with jquery. Just an example. I'm sure theres a better vanilla JS way of doing it.

Comment: this only works if you have jquery. and if you check your console it should output it into base64.

Just change the id's so it matches your html.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload image using iframe, using iframe and ajax image will upload without page refresh.
You can try using my sample.
HTML:

```
<form id="registerFormValidation" name="registerFormValidation" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<div id="main">
<input name="imgInp" id="imgInp" size="27" type="file" />
<input type="button" name="action" value="Upload" onclick="upload()"/>
<iframe id='my_iframe' name='my_iframe' src="">
</iframe>
</div>    
</form>
```

This is my JS:

```
function upload()
{
//'my_iframe' is the name of the iframe
document.getElementById('registerFormValidation').target = 'my_iframe';
document.getElementById('registerFormValidation').submit();
}
```

And For Server side you can use simple Ajax method or Custom method.If you use ajax method then action will be `action="javascript:submitForm();"` and if you use custom method then you can use your function name.